# Django automatically converting datetime string to local timezone

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

I am adding timestamp in my payload and storing it in the database for every record.

Suppose say a part of my payload is `{"content":[{"timestamp":"2017-12-12 08:05:30"}]`

This is how I process it.

```
content['timestamp'] = parser.parse(content['timestamp'],dayfirst=True)
```

My model has timestamp field as :

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

When I check in my database it stores timestamp field as :

```
2017-12-12 13:35:30
```

Which should be stored as it is as per my requirement. `2017-12-12 08:05:30`

i.e it stores the timestamp field + my local timezone(+5:30) hours.

I want it to store the timestamp field as it is.

I tried other posts where they suggest using `del os.environ['TZ']`.

Any idea what I may have done which causes this or what could I do to avoid this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to this Question the problem is when django converts datetime to postgres timestamptz in the database.

[Postgres prevent timestamp with timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829024/postgres-prevent-timestamp-with-timezone-conversion)

So I need to have timestamp field in PostgreSQL

In order to do that , I need to use the answer posted in this question.

[Can we have django DatetimeField without timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884639/can-we-have-django-datetimefield-without-timezone)

Where I need to specify USE_TZ = False in the settings.

This makes sure while migrating PostgreSQL considers datetimefield to be converted to timestamp and not timestamptz .

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timezone in settings.py

Here is the list of valid timezones:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

You can use

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

for UTC+05:30

Reference from [Selcuk Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311354/how-to-set-the-timezone-in-django)

Comment: Yes, we can , I had set it to UTC. Here I don't wish to use timezone but store it as it is.